# How to add a private remote git repository in PhpStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitlab

This might seem like a stupid question but I can't find the information in the PhpStorm docs.

- I have created a private, empty git repository on GitLab.
- I created a local project with composer to install a framework.

Now I want to connect this local project with the private repository on GitLab.

But every time I try to add the remote I can't find an option to add any credentials of sorts so naturally it fails telling me it can't find the remote or it got rejected.

I know there are other ways to do this but I've done a setup like this before a long time ago.

Comment: PhpStom hasn't good support of git. For GUI git using you can try  SmartGit solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you'd normally do

```
git remote add gitlab url-to-gitlab-repo
git push gitlab master
```

Comment: ah i guess the gitlab part was missing... wow now i feel stupid. thank you!

Comment: @FuriousGamer may octocat be with you!